# Is there any logic to how SFDC serializes classes to JSON?

Tags: apex, json, apexrest, serialization

I'm working on documentation for a number of APEX REST API endpoints which returned user-defined types. I'm struggling to write the documentation since the order of how things are serialized into JSON seems to change every time I compile the class.

The [JSON docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_serialize) and google aren't provided much insight. Has anyone figured out how Salesforce serializes user-defined types?

As an example, given the following response type

```
public class Example {
  public String foo { get; private set; }
  public String bar { get; private set; }
}
```

How do I know if it'll serialize to

```
{"foo": "value", "bar": "value"}
```

Or

```
{"bar": "value", "foo": "value"}
```

While the above example doesn't really make much a difference several endpoints have very large response types and ideally I'd like to be able to have the docs match whatever Salesforce sends back.

Answer (score 2):

This [critical update](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/pages/release-notes/rn_apex_maps_and_sets_iteration_order.htm) may make your question a little easier to work around. If you choose to enable it there isn't a defined order for iterating maps, but whatever that order is it will be consistent. So while you can't really predict what the json output will be you can just look at what it is, and know that it will continue to come that way.

Answer (score 0):

This is your class

```
public class Example {
  public String foo { get;set; }
  public String bar { get;set; }
}
```

Step 1 - Create the instance of the class and populate the values as below :

```
Example ex = new Example();
ex.foo = 'This is my JSON Serializer';
ex.bar = 'Just using JSON Helper Methods';
```

Step 2 : invoke the static JSON Helper methods as below passing the instance of class you created:

```
String formattedJSON = **JSON.serialize**(ex);
System.debug('formattedJSON-->>>'+formattedJSON);
```

Sep 3 : Get the result :)

> 08:11:56:083 USER_DEBUG [6]|DEBUG|formattedJSON-->>>{"foo":"This is my JSON Serializer","bar":"Just using JSON Helper Methods"}

Comment: You might mention that the order (or even *presence*) of the values is version dependent. For example, last time I tried serializing, everything came out in order, and trying it just now resulted in it coming out in declaration order.

Comment: @sfdcfox that's the rub, it seems to change all the time. Don't really care so much about the order, just wish it would be consistent ...

Comment: @kaw this is kind of circular definition, I can test the endpoint and see the serialization, the difficulty is that it's not consistent and doesn't appear to have any predictable order (i.e. alphabetical, declaration order, etc.)

Comment: i would believe that should not matter much given that json implementation also internally makes use of map kind of a structure and sequence would always vary in case of map implementation. This would be true for every kind of language where map is being used.

Comment: i would believe that should not matter much given that json implementation also internally makes use of map kind of a structure and sequence would always vary in case of map implementation. This would be true for every kind of language where map is being used.

Comment: Is there any specific requirement, why you would sequence to be in a specific order ?

Comment: @KawSumit I'm writing documentation, and people go ape sh*t when they see differences between the docs and what they actual get. Secondarily, for big serializations a random scattering of keys and values is really hard to read in the docs. Once people start programming against it the order doesn't matter in the least, just something for us humans who like being able to scan things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21663/discussion-between-kaw-sumit-and-ralph-callaway).